# Captcha doesn't work online

Tags: php, captcha

I'm using xampp for localhost and it works.

It doesn't work online (using **000webhost** service), and the code is exactly the same.

I'm using 3 (three) files here to make it work: 
***enviarmensaje.php*** (form) 
***enviar.php*** (action) 
***captcha.php***

The first one is about the form: ***enviarmensaje.php***

```
<form id="consulta" action="enviar.php" method="post">
    <!-- captcha -->
    <label for="captcha"><p>Captcha:</p></label>
    <img src="captcha.php" style="display:block" />
    <input type="text" size="16" id="captcha" name="captcha" tabindex="45"  value="<?php if(isset($_SESSION['e'])) echo isset($_SESSION['raw_captcha']) ? $_SESSION['raw_captcha'] : "";  ?>" required/>
    <!-- end captcha -->
    <input type="submit" value="Enviar mensaje" tabindex="50" style="margin-top: 30px;">
</form>
```

The action file, which is ***enviar.php*** :

```
<?php
    session_start();
    require_once('_includes/funciones.php');




    if(strtoupper($_REQUEST["captcha"]) == $_SESSION["captcha"]){
            // REMPLAZO EL CAPTCHA USADO POR UN TEXTO LARGO PARA EVITAR QUE SE VUELVA A INTENTAR
        $_SESSION["captcha"] = md5(rand()*time());
            // INSERTA EL CÓDIGO EXITOSO AQUI

        $to = "insertmail@here.com";
        $subject = "Consulta de {$_POST['nombre']}";
        $message = "Consulta de {$_POST['nombre']} <br> {$_POST['telefono']} | {$_POST['email']} <br><br>{$_POST['mensaje']}";

        mail($to ,$subject , $message);

        $_SESSION['c'] = "<span style=\"color: lime;\">Gracias! Contestaremos su consulta a la brevedad!</span>";

    }else{
            // REMPLAZO EL CAPTCHA USADO POR UN TEXTO LARGO PARA EVITAR QUE SE VUELVA A INTENTAR
        $_SESSION["raw_captcha"] = $_REQUEST["captcha"];
        $_SESSION["captcha"] = md5(rand()*time());
            // INSERTA EL CÓDIGO DE ERROR AQUÍ
        $_SESSION['nombre'] = $_POST['nombre'];
        $_SESSION['email'] = $_POST['email'];
        $_SESSION['telefono'] = $_POST['telefono'];
        $_SESSION['mensaje'] = $_POST['mensaje'];

        $_SESSION['e'] = "<span style=\"color: red;\">Captcha incorrecto, inténtelo de nuevo.</span>";
    }
    redirect_to("contacto.php?p=1");
?>
```

And just in case, the ***captcha.php***

```
<?php 
    ###########################################################################################
    #
    #  CAPTCHA FÁCIL 1.0
    #
    #  Autor: Alejandro Martín Núñez
    #  Contact: alemnunez at gmail dot com
    #  Date: October 10, 2009
    #
    #  COMO USAR CAPTCHA FÁCIL
    #
    #  FORMULARIO
    #  En el formulario que deseas validar, inserta el siguiente código:
    #  
    #  <img src="captcha.php" /><br/>
    #  <input type="text" size="12" name="captcha" />
    #
    #
    #  VERIFICACIÓN
    #  Al procesar el formulario, compara el contenido del campo que 
    #  completó el usuario con el contenido de $_SESSION["captcha"] 
    #  que generó este programa:
    #
    #  session_start();
    #  if(strtoupper($_REQUEST["captcha"]) == $_SESSION["captcha"]){
    #    // REMPLAZO EL CAPTCHA USADO POR UN TEXTO LARGO PARA EVITAR QUE SE VUELVA A INTENTAR
    #    $_SESSION["captcha"] = md5(rand()*time());
    #    // INSERTA EL CÓDIGO EXITOSO AQUI
    #  }else{
    #    // REMPLAZO EL CAPTCHA USADO POR UN TEXTO LARGO PARA EVITAR QUE SE VUELVA A INTENTAR
    #    $_SESSION["captcha"] = md5(rand()*time());
    #    // INSERTA EL CÓDIGO DE ERROR AQUÍ
    #  }
    #
    #  
    #  OLVIDÁ EL SPAM!
    #
    ###########################################################################################

    #create image and set background color
    $captcha = imagecreatetruecolor(120,35);
    $color = rand(128,160);
    $background_color = imagecolorallocate($captcha, $color, $color, $color);
    imagefill($captcha, 0, 0, $background_color);

    #draw some lines
    for($i=0;$i<10;$i++){
        $color = rand(48,96);
        imageline($captcha, rand(0,130),rand(0,35), rand(0,130), rand(0,35),imagecolorallocate($captcha, $color, $color, $color));
    }

    #generate a random string of 5 characters
    $string = substr(md5(rand()*time()),0,5);

    #make string uppercase and replace "O" and "0" to avoid mistakes
    $string = strtoupper($string);
    $string = str_replace("O","B", $string);
    $string = str_replace("0","C", $string);

    #save string in session "captcha" key
    session_start();
    $_SESSION["captcha"]=$string;

    #place each character in a random position
    putenv('GDFONTPATH=' . realpath('.'));
    $font = 'arial.ttf';
    for($i=0;$i<5;$i++){
        $color = rand(0,32);
        if(file_exists($font)){
            $x=4+$i*23+rand(0,6);
            $y=rand(18,28);
            imagettftext  ($captcha, 15, rand(-25,25), $x, $y, imagecolorallocate($captcha, $color, $color, $color), $font, $string[$i]);
        }else{
            $x=5+$i*24+rand(0,6);
            $y=rand(1,18);
            imagestring($captcha, 5, $x, $y, $string[$i], imagecolorallocate($captcha, $color, $color, $color));
        }
    }

    #applies distorsion to image
    $matrix = array(array(1, 1, 1), array(1.0, 7, 1.0), array(1, 1, 1));
    imageconvolution($captcha, $matrix, 16, 32);

    #avoids catching
    header("Expires: 0");
    header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
    header("Cache-Control: private",false); 

    #return the image
    header("Content-type: image/gif");
    imagejpeg($captcha);
?>
```

Here's the website where it should work: http://matricestecnicas.webege.com/contacto.php?p=1

Comment: `Fatal error: Call to undefined function imageconvolution() in /home/a2110031/public_html/captcha.php on line 82`

Comment: Maybe it has to do with the php version in which is working. But how did you get that error?

Comment: Right click on the broken image link, then press "View Image"

Comment: Some friend of mine recommended to use the Google Recaptcha. I read the how to install and now I realize it's easy. http://www.google.com/recaptcha/ (I was sleepy when I read it, lol)